# Drop down having same name

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to select a drop down if 2 drop down have the same name? I need to select both the drop downs.both the drop downs having the same name. The Id's for the drop downs are dynamically generated. Please help.

1.

```
<select id="trin" 
    class="ng-scope ng-valid-r-min non-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse 
           ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched"
    ng-model="formData.agesOfChildren[nr]" 
    r-floating-label="Alder på barn" 
    tooltip="" r-min="1" 
    required="" only-digits="" 
    tabindex="0" name="agesOfChildren">
```

2.

```
<select id="ywf1" 
   class="ng-scope ng-valid-r-min non-empty 
          ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" 
   ng-model="formData.agesOfChildren[nr]" 
   r-floating-label="Alder på barn"
   tooltip="" r-min="1" 
   required="" only-digits="" 
   tabindex="0" name="agesOfChildren">
```

Comment: 1.<select id="trin" class="ng-scope ng-valid-r-min non-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" ng-model="formData.agesOfChildren[nr]" r-floating-label="Alder på barn" tooltip="" r-min="1" required="" only-digits="" tabindex="0" name="agesOfChildren">

2.<select id="ywf1" class="ng-scope ng-valid-r-min non-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" ng-model="formData.agesOfChildren[nr]" r-floating-label="Alder på barn" tooltip="" r-min="1" required="" only-digits="" tabindex="0" name="agesOfChildren">

Comment: Dont they have different IDs? Why do you say they are same? You can always use ID as the locator.

Comment: I tried with id but no selection

Comment: I tried like this  new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("trin"))).selectByVisibleText("12");

Comment: @user123: Either select by xpath or class name or name, since the id is dynamically generated.

Comment: @Little Panda, can you please send me the code using xpath

Comment: @LittlePanda is it a good practice to use xpath by the method provided by you, like it may change if we add any fields?

Comment: @user123: Is it possible for you to give the url you are working on? Also, can you confirm if the id's are dynamically generated. If not, then why are you not trying to select them using id? Also, please post the code you have tried.

Comment: @user123: Since you claim that id, class, name is not working for you, we are left with xpath and css. Since xpath is vulnerable to changes, we should make sure to use a **well formed xpath**.

Comment: @LittlePanda , Yes ids are generating dynamically. the problem when giving name is that it will only select the first drop down because two are having the same name. Class is also same for both.

Comment: @user123: Yes thats why I have suggested that xpath or css will be the only way. Please perform the steps given in my answer and post your findings in your question. The xpath will be different for the dropdowns

Comment: Yes. Thats an option. But the code wont work if the developers change any fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the ID is generated, there really aren't a whole lot of ways to distinguish one of these elements from another, besides the DOM structure.

It is possible you could look at the values of the possible selections and construct your selector that way, but if those are the same/similar, it would not help either.

Using DOM structure:

## First Select Element:

```
//select[@class="ng-scope ng-valid-r-min non-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched"][1]
```

## Second Select Element:

```
//select[@class="ng-scope ng-valid-r-min non-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched"][2]
```

I usually try to steer away from DOM structure selectors, due to the many ways the DOM can be manipulated and changed via javascript, but in this situation, there really isn't another option beyond contacting the developers and asking them to add a differentiating class to each of these.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two dropdowns and both of them have same attributes and theirs ids are generated. But, the xpath will be different for them.

You have to inspect both the dropdowns from your browser. Do the following:

1. Right click on each dropdown in Chrome
2. Select Inspect Element
3. Right click on highlighted code and select Copy Xpath OR CSSPath

Comment: I think this might work, but it would more than likely create an incredibly brittle selector.

Comment: @aholt: I agree Xpath is not preferred, but other selectors for both the dropdowns are same. Xpath has to be a well formed one.

Comment: Correct.   My comment was more along the lines that using the "Copy XPath" option within Chrome will probably create a very brittle XPath selector.

Personally, I haven't seen much of a difference in using XPath vs CSS selector beyond preference.  There used to be performance differences, but they are nonexistent now.

Comment: @aholt: In this case, I didnt see anything in the html code to directly write two different XPaths.

Answer (score -1):

try this Xpath

for Second Dropdown

```
//select[@class='ng-scope ng-valid-r-min non-empty 
      ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched'][1]
```

for First Drop Down

```
//select[@class='ng-scope ng-valid-r-min non-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse 
       ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched'][2]
```

Comment: Those two selectors are the same.

Comment: Please check i had modified the answer, sorry for the previous answer i thought like class are different and if this dont work you can handle that using list of webelement

Comment: Now the selectors are the exact same as the ones in my answer.   lol